# commondatastorage v/s storage request end points

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

To share Google Cloud Storage objects we have this [API request](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#endpoints) -

http://neelam-sharma.storage.googleapis.com/test.html

Earlier this request end point was **commondatastorage** as -

http://neelam-sharma.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/test.html

Both requests are working, do you redirect all the request from commondatastorage to storage end point?

What's the best way to access objects via this type of URL? What's the difference between these two URLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`commondatastorage` was the previous name for accessing cloud storage. Please update to use the new URLs. You can find up-to-date information about request URIs on the [Google Cloud Storage Request URIs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-uris) page.

Comment: Thanks jterrace, what can harm if I do not update to new name, will it slow access of objects?

Comment: No, it won't harm anything, but you should still upgrade to the new URLs.

Comment: I'm faced with some bugs lately where the two urls somehow point to different files - so they don't seem to be equal any longer.

Comment: @Kevin That sounds quite troublesome. Could you clarify? And which URL was the right one? The new one, I hope?